# Nested flexbox not working with scrollbar/overflow auto

Tags: flexbox, overflow

I'm working on a layout with these requirements:

- Height is controlled by outermost `<div>`
- The last element in each box fills its box's height, AND its content doesn't overflow i.e. show a scrollbar if it's too long.

My current solution is using `flex-direction: column`, `flex: 1` and `overflow: auto`. However, it doesn't work with nested flexbox:

1. No nesting: my solution works

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>sth</div>
  <div class="bottom">
          "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
  </div>
</div>
```

2. With nesting: my solution doesn't work

```css
.wrapper-outer {
  height: 100px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>sth</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>sth</div>
    <div class="bottom">
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make this work, other than completely avoid nesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code: 1. you didn't set the class `.wrapper-outer` on your outermost div and 2. the overflow is not handled.

By adding the missing class and `overflow: auto;` to `.wrapper` you should get your desired result:

```css
.wrapper-outer {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-outer">
  <div>sth</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>sth</div>
    <div class="bottom">
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
      sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora
      incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea
      voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```